# using relative path to open excel file in visual studio using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I seem to be having a problem opening an excel file with a relative path in visual studio. The file is being saved to:

```
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Filename.xls
```

on any machine. I have tried using:

```
Process.Start(@"~\Documents\Filename.xls");
```

to open the excel file, but it throws an error saying the file location cannot be found. Is there something I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The '~' character is used in Linux.

With the following code you can obtain the path for special folders:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

The MyDocuments can be replaced for other Windows specific folder like:

- UserProfile
- MyPictures
- Desktop

Answer (score 0):

'~' is not a valid path identifier in Windows (It does refer to the home directory on *nix). I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps you want SpecialFolder [see description here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Will return: C:\Users\'UserName'\Documents\

Answer (score 0):

You could use combine to get the full path

```
var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var fullPath.Combine(folderPath, "filename.xls");
Process.Start(fullPath);
```

If you know the relative path to the working folder use

```
var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(relPath);
```